# How to draw map layer only inside FeatureGroup elements in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

For example, I have two map layers: open street maps and our own one. Both can be defined this way:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(mapObject);
```

The question is in that I do not need to draw the second layer on a whole map, but only inside elements of `L.FeatureGroup`:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(mapObject);
```

Especially inside polygons, rectangles, etc... Is that possible with leaflet? If yes, how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276012/prevent-tiles-outside-of-polygon-from-loading/34281620#34281620

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the [`bounds` option of your `L.TileLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#gridlayer-bounds), i.e.:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup( .... );

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: ...,
    bounds: drawnItems.getBounds()
}).addTo(mapObject);
```

Another approach would be to look at the [list of plugins for tile display](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display), and use either [TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) or [leaflet-tilelayer-mask](https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask) (keep in mind that more plugins might be applicable, and more plugins might appear in the future).