# LeafletJs only show one country

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm using Leafletjs with D3 to show a map.

I only want to show the UK in the map.

Is it possible with Leaflet and D3 to only show the UK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dim/Hide rest of map around country with leaflet.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652189/dim-hide-rest-of-map-around-country-with-leaflet-js)

Answer (score 8):

It is certainly possible.

Now the solution depends whether you want to use D3 to draw the UK, or you want to get it from a Tile Server.

In the latter case, there is a more recent solution than the one proposed in the link in xmojmr's comment.

See [Prevent tiles outside of polygon from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276012/prevent-tiles-outside-of-polygon-from-loading/34281620#34281620)

The idea is to use the [TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas plugin](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas), which you can specify a GeoJSON `boundary` option to hide everything that is not within that GeoJSON geometry.

> BoundaryCanvas is a plugin for Leaflet mapping library to draw tiled raster layers with arbitrary boundary. HTML5 Canvas is used for rendering.

Live demo with a rough UK shape:

```js
var map = L.map("map");

$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/johan/world.geo.json/34c96bba/countries/GBR.geo.json').then(function(geoJSON) {
  var osm = new L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    boundary: geoJSON,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, UK shape <a href="https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json">johan/word.geo.json</a>'
  });
  map.addLayer(osm);
  var ukLayer = L.geoJSON(geoJSON);
  map.fitBounds(ukLayer.getBounds());
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas/f00b4d35/src/BoundaryCanvas.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: maybe you should use [nominatim uk polygon](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=uk&polygon_geojson=1&format=json) for more details (border details)